# How to set color of a particular row in flex list control for mobile

Tags: apache-flex, list, mobile, air, adobe

I have a list in flex mobile project which contains multiple rows. I want to set color of specific rows based on some logic.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a Custom Item Renderer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS03d33b8076db57b9-23c04461124bbeca597-8000.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS684a1733bf2efe8a4bab272a129d72a6e2f-7ffe.html

Everything you need should be here if you still have questions be more specific what is the issue you encounter?